# How to create a citation graph using Bibtex and XML

Tags: bibtex, citing, xml

I would like to include a citation graph for all the citations in my bibliography. My question is how to parse the graph file (in XML format), replacing the `\cite{...}` keys with the correct number from the bibliography for my document.

I'll illustrate what I'm trying to do with a minimal example. Let's suppose my document has just 2 citations, DocA and DocB. DocA is itself included in the bibliography of DocB, so the citation graph has one directed edge. I define this graph in XML format using GEXF (http://gexf.net/format/) as follows:

```
<graph defaultedgetype="directed">
<nodes>
   <node id="0" label="\cite{DocA}" />
   <node id="1" label="\cite{DocB}" />
</nodes>
<edges>
   <edge id="0" source="1" target="0" />
</edges>
</graph>
```

I can load this file into Gephi (https://gephi.org/) to produce a visualisation which I output as PDF and import as an image in my LaTeX source file.

In the LaTeX file, I also have `\cite{DocA}` and `\cite{DocB}` somewhere, which will be replaced by numbers `[1]` and `[2]` in the document's bibliography.

What I want to do is replace `\cite{DocA}` and `\cite{DocB}` in the XML file with `[1]` and `[2]` so that they correspond to the numbers in the document bibliography. Can I use BibTeX to do this?

If I can get this to work, it should provide a pretty visualisation of how the documents in my bibliography relate to each other.

Comment: Can you add an image to show us how the visualisation will look and how/were it should be added in your LaTeX code? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful ...

Comment: The visualisation is simply a PDF which is included using \includegraphics in the normal way. I don't need help with that part. The point is that I need to substitute "\cite{DocA}" in the XML file above with "1" (or whatever number "DocA" is in the LaTeX output file).

Comment: The lookup is in the aux file, things like `\bibcite{grimm}{1}` or with hyperref `\bibcite{asakawa2003cine}{{1}{}{{}}{{}}}` tell you that `grimm` is `[1]` so you just need to grep for bibcite in the aux file and then pull that data in using a tool of your choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lookup is in the `aux` file, things like

```
\bibcite{grimm}{1}
```

or with hyperref

```
\bibcite{grimm}{{1}{}{{}}{{}}}
```

tell you that `grimm` is `[1]` so you just need to `grep` for `bibcite` in the `aux` file and then pull that data in using a tool of your choice.